# What kind of hash returns lower and upper case characters?

Tags: hash, base64, md5, sha1, sha

Sorry for my bad English...
The string:

NFkwYnB5cjA0V09HK1Q2SHZXZHNydz09

I think it's a MD5 hash, but a MD5 returns only lower case characters and, as you can see, the result returns the both (lower and upper case).

Comment: I don't think that's a hash. It looks like a partial fragment of a base64 encoded string. Take a look at the hashes on the bottom of [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=hi). All hashes that I know are hexadecimal (0-9, a-f, and/or A-F).

Comment: you can decode your base64 string from here http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=base64&action=decode&charset=us_ascii

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not true that MD5 returns only lowercase characters.

A [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) returns a sequence of *bytes*, not a string. To print out bytes, you need a [binary-to-text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding). Whether there are uppercase characters in the printed string depends completely on which binary-to-text encoding you choose. For example, [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) uses two character cases, which means you can have both uppercase and lowercase characters, while [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) uses only one case.